# What is the correct way to place keys and messages without repeating too much code (expl3)

Tags: expl3, package-writing, l3keys

I am trying to put error messages for invalid `keys` in a package, some keys are available for the package, others can be accessed with the command `\mypkgset` and others are only available as options of some command.

The messages I am placing are similar, and I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it. This is my example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mypkg.sty}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypkg}{2019/09/26}{0.1}{A dummy pkg}
% keys for pkg options, only mykey-a, print-b and pkgkey
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
  {
    mykey-a .tl_set:N         = \l_dummy_a_keya_tl,
    mykey-a .initial:n        = value-a,
    mykey-a .value_required:n = true,
    print-b .bool_set:N       = \l_dummy_b_bool,
    print-b .initial:n        = false,
    print-b .default:n        = true,
    pkgkey  .tl_set:N         = \l_dummy_pkg_key_tl,
    pkgkey  .initial:n        = pkg-value,
    pkgkey  .value_required:n = true
  }
\ProcessKeysOptions { mypkg }
% Add more keys for mypkgset
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
  {
    print-a .bool_set:N       = \l_dummy_a_bool,
    print-a .initial:n        = false,
    print-a .default:n        = true,
    mykey-b .tl_set:N         = \l_dummy_b_keyb_tl,
    mykey-b .initial:n        = value-b,
    mykey-b .value_required:n = true,
    mykey-c .tl_set:N         = \l_dummy_c_keyc_tl,
    mykey-c .initial:n        = value-c,
    mykey-c .value_required:n = true,
    print-c .bool_set:N       = \l_dummy_c_bool,
    print-c .initial:n        = false,
    print-c .default:n        = true
  }
% \mypkgset
\NewDocumentCommand { \mypkgset } { m }
  { \keys_set:nn { mypkg } {#1} }

% Set keys for \dummya
\keys_define:nn { mypkg / dummy-a }
  {
    print-a .meta:nn   = { mypkg } { print-a = #1 },
    print-a .default:n = true, % need, if not print-a show Error
    mykey-a .meta:nn   = { mypkg } { mykey-a = #1 },
    unknown .code:n    = { \__mypkg_parse_dummy_a_keys:n {#1} }
  }
% Parse unknown keys for \dummya
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_parse_dummy_a_keys:n #1
  { \exp_args:NV \__mypkg_parse_dummy_a_keys:nn \l_keys_key_tl {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_parse_dummy_a_keys:nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
      { \msg_error:nnn { mypkg } { dummy-a-key-unknown } {#1} }
      { \msg_error:nnnn { mypkg } { dummy-a-key-value-unknown } {#1} {#2} }
  }
% Errors for  \dummya
\msg_new:nnnn { mypkg } { dummy-a-key-unknown }
  { The~key~'#1'~is~unknown~by~'\c_backslash_str dummya'~and~is~being~ignored.}
  { The~command~'\c_backslash_str dummya'~does~not~have~a~key~called~'#1'.}
\msg_new:nnnn { mypkg } { dummy-a-key-value-unknown }
  { The~key~'#1=#2'~is~unknown~by~'\c_backslash_str dummya'~and~is~being~ignored. }
  { The~command~'\c_backslash_str dummya'~does~not~have~a~key~called~'#1'.}

% Set keys for \dummyb
\tl_new:N \l_mypkg_txt_tl
\keys_define:nn { mypkg / dummy-b }
  {
    print-b .meta:nn   = { mypkg } { print-b = #1 },
    print-b .default:n = true, % need, if not print-b show Error
    mykey-b .meta:nn   = { mypkg } { mykey-b = #1 },
    mytext  .code:n    = { \tl_set:Nn \l_mypkg_txt_tl {#1} },% only in \dummyb
    unknown .code:n    = { \__mypkg_parse_dummy_b_keys:n {#1} }
  }
% Parse unknown keys for \dummyb
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_parse_dummy_b_keys:n #1
  { \exp_args:NV \__mypkg_parse_dummy_b_keys:nn \l_keys_key_tl {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_parse_dummy_b_keys:nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
      { \msg_error:nnn { mypkg } { dummy-b-key-unknown } {#1} }
      { \msg_error:nnnn { mypkg } { dummy-b-key-value-unknown } {#1} {#2} }
  }
% Errors for  \dummyb
\msg_new:nnnn { mypkg } { dummy-b-key-unknown }
  { The~key~'#1'~is~unknown~by~'\c_backslash_str dummyb'~and~is~being~ignored.}
  { The~command~'\c_backslash_str dummyb'~does~not~have~a~key~called~'#1'.}
\msg_new:nnnn { mypkg } { dummy-b-key-value-unknown }
  { The~key~'#1=#2'~is~unknown~by~'\c_backslash_str dummyb'~and~is~being~ignored. }
  { The~command~'\c_backslash_str dummyb'~does~not~have~a~key~called~'#1'.}

% Set keys for envdummy
\keys_define:nn { mypkg / dummy-env }
  {
    print-c .meta:nn   = { mypkg } { print-c = #1 },
    print-c .default:n = true, % need, if not print-c show Error
    mykey-c .meta:nn   = { mypkg } { mykey-c = #1 },
    unknown .code:n    = { \__mypkg_parse_dummy_env_keys:n {#1} }
  }

% Parse unknown keys for envdummy
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_parse_dummy_env_keys:n #1
  { \exp_args:NV \__mypkg_parse_dummy_env_keys:nn \l_keys_key_tl {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_parse_dummy_env_keys:nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
      { \msg_error:nnn { mypkg } { dummy-env-key-unknown } {#1} }
      { \msg_error:nnnn { mypkg } { dummy-env-key-value-unknown } {#1} {#2} }
  }
% Errors for  envdummy
\msg_new:nnnn { mypkg } { dummy-env-key-unknown }
  { The~key~'#1'~is~unknown~by~'envdummy'~environment~and~is~being~ignored.}
  { The~environment~'envdummy'~does~not~have~a~key~called~'#1'.}
\msg_new:nnnn { mypkg } { dummy-env-key-value-unknown }
  { The~key~'#1=#2'~is~unknown~by~'envdummy'~environment~and~is~being~ignored.}
  { The~environment~'envdummy'~does~not~have~a~key~called~'#1'.}

% dummy-a
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_dummy_a:n #1
  {
    This~is~\texttt{"#1"}~with~\texttt{"mykey-a=\tl_use:N \l_dummy_a_keya_tl"}~
    and~\texttt{"\bool_if:nTF { \l_dummy_a_bool } { print-a=true } { print-a=false }"}
  }

% dummy-b
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_dummy_b:n #1
  {
    This~is~\texttt{"#1"}~with~\texttt{"mykey-b=\tl_use:N \l_dummy_b_keyb_tl"}~
    and~\texttt{"\bool_if:nTF { \l_dummy_b_bool } { print-b=true } { print-b=false }"}\par
    and~\texttt{"mytext=\tl_use:N \l_mypkg_txt_tl"}
  }

% envdummy
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_dummy_env:
  {
    with~\texttt{"mykey-c=\tl_use:N \l_dummy_c_keyc_tl"}~
    and~\texttt{"\bool_if:nTF { \l_dummy_c_bool } { print-c=true } { print-c=false }"}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \dummya }{ O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \IfValueT {#1} { \keys_set:nn {  mypkg / dummy-a } {#1} }
      \__mypkg_dummy_a:n {#2}
    \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \dummyb }{ O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \IfValueT {#1} { \keys_set:nn {  mypkg / dummy-b } {#1} }
      \__mypkg_dummy_b:n {#2}
    \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment { envdummy } { O{} b}
  {
    \group_begin:
      \IfValueT {#1} { \keys_set:nn {  mypkg / dummy-env } {#1} }
      This~is~\texttt{"#2"}~
  }
  {
      \__mypkg_dummy_env:
    \group_end:
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[print-b,pkgkey=some]{mypkg}
\begin{document}
\dummya[mykey-a=other-a,print-a]{A dummya test 1}\par
\dummyb[mykey-b=other-b,mytext={A text for test}]{A dummyb test 1}\par
\begin{envdummy}[mykey-c=other-c]
A envdummy test 1
\end{envdummy}

\mypkgset{muu=kkkk}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can pass more arguments to the message. If you do this, you avoid repeating so much text when defining the messages, but you have to specify more information when using them. I tend to do this, but, it seems to me, it is swings and roundabouts.

Comment: @crf: I absolutely understand your comment, can you turn it into an answer not to leave the question open?